# MVC pagination in html table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a search form with search button. When user enters all the search input fields and press the search button will return only top 10 records in the html table in the same page. I have done until this.

When user press the next page button i have to retain the values entered by user and send it to the database and get next 10 records.

When I press the search button (first http post) the view model has all the values entered by the user but when I press the next page button click(second post) the view model is not retaining the values entered by the user in the search input fields.

I was advised to NOT to use temp data to pass values from one action to another action. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: i haven't done the coding yet. i am looking for the sample.

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered PagedList library for pagination? All what you have to do is to reference PagedList library in your ASP.NET MVC application

To install PagedList.Mvc, run the following command in the Package Manager Console. You can use NuGet to get this package too.

```
PM> Install-Package PagedList.Mvc
```

Your viewmodel

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
        public int QuestionId { get; set; }
        public string QuestionName { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller, reference PagedList

```
using PagedList;
and the Index method of your controller will be something like

public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
            var questions = new[] {
                new QuestionViewModel { QuestionId = 1, QuestionName = "Question 1" },
                new QuestionViewModel { QuestionId = 1, QuestionName = "Question 2" },
                new QuestionViewModel { QuestionId = 1, QuestionName = "Question 3" },
                new QuestionViewModel { QuestionId = 1, QuestionName = "Question 4" }
            };

            int pageSize = 3;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(questions.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

And your Index view

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<ViewModel.QuestionViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc; 
<link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<table>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuestionName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<br />

Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }) )
```

And the resultant screen would look like

[image]

Comment: i'll get million records when i get a results. In your eg. `var question = ` i can't bind million records to this variable. When i press 2nd page i have to make another call to the DB and get the 2nd set of records. stored procedure will take care of returning 2nd set of records. but i have pass the same search input values when i press 2nd page button.

Comment: Then you have to write your own custom code to do that, it should not be that difficult. If the search input values are lost upon click of `next page button` then I guess you are resetting the view model values some where. If you are using view model with strongly types view then it should persist input values unless you re-initialize the vm class.

Comment: @SaravananGengan... if you don't do a ".ToList()" your query is not executed in the database. So... it is only executed when you do questions.ToPagedList(1,20). So, the list will only have 20 records. Do a try with this... and check if you need other solution.

Comment: The project has been moved to https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList

Answer (score 1):

You should really try to use an existing grid that supports this already, for example check out: [Datatables](http://datatables.net).

It is a JQuery based grid that handles the paging, filtering, sorting, etc. for you. 
And if you have a lot of data it even allows you to retrieve it server-side. Remember: ***"do not reinvent the wheel"***

Comment: i was not allowed to use datatables. Can we do this using only MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to pass current search params in the PAGE action. Remember that in ASP.NET MVC you need to re-post the information to the server... as it doesn't save state.

If you are using **PagedList** package, you do:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.YourList, page => Url.Action("PostAction", new { page, Model.SearchString,Model.OtherFilter, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort}))
```

If you are not, check this out: https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList

There you can see some code examples... but the component can be installed via [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList).

Here in Stackoverflow you can see lots of questions/answers about PagedList