# how to use Gridview in mvc for dynamically data

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

AS we can use Gridview in asp.net similarly how to use in mvc5 for dynamically data`enter code here`

Comment: Please first check how to ask question otherwise your question will be downvoted by others and you will not be able to ask any further questions here.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149947/mvc-pagination-in-html-table here you can refer how to implement the Grid kind of functionality in ASP.NET MVC or you can learn from here as well - https://datatables.net/manual/